# Desenvolver para iOS usando C# no Visual Studio

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Eu já desenvolvo em Java/Android, e queria desenvolver para iOS, porém o custo de ter um Mac esta caro, eu já tenho um iPhone. Vi que era possivel desenvolver usando C# no Visual Studio para iOS.

Então, o Xamarin vale a pena? Eu posso desenvolver tranquilamente usando Windows? E a comunidade do Xamarin como anda em relação a conteúdos?

Comment: Pode fazer um [Hackintosh](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-hackintosh-part-1--cms-21473) ;) . . . . . Fiz uma revisão editorial na sua pergunta para tentar deixá-la mais clara e evitar seu fechamento como "Principalmente baseada em opiniões".

Comment: Hackintosh nunca consegui, sempre da erro nas instalações.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, por vários motivos:

- Desenvolvimento de aplicativos para Mac, Windows e Android com o mesmo código
- Boa ferramenta de desenvolvimento (Xamarin Studio e **Visual Studio**)
- Integração direta com os emuladores
- Pacote de plugins e bibliotecas desenvolvidos pela comunidade
- Suporte no fórum oficial (comunidade) ou direto com a equipe do Xamarin.

E outras vantagens da linguagem C#, como **Linq**!

Desde que adquiri a licença não me arrependo!

Comment: Xamarin tem que pagar? não sabia

Comment: Tem a versão free que não suporta Visual Studio e o Xamarin.Forms. O visual studio não é problema, pois o Xamarin Studio é muito bom, já o Xamarin.Forms permite com o mesmo código gerar UI pra ambos os SO. No caso você vai poder aproveitar core, bibliotecas e outras coisas mas a UI vai ter que desenhar um para cada SO. No meu ver não é problema, pior é desenvolver 2 aplicações.

Comment: Mas olha só: Até onde sei, mesmo com o Xamarin é necessário ter um Mac. Isso confere?

Comment: Sim, você tem duas opções: 1. Usar o Mac com Windows sobre uma máquina virtual com o visual studio instalado ou usar o visual studio e windows com um mac de host. No caso ele precisa para iPhone que vai ser o host!

Comment: Quanto custa a licença? eu posso usar em computadores diferente a mesma licença?

Comment: $89/mês ou $999/anualmente. Sim é uma licença para empresas! https://store.xamarin.com/ nesse link você consegue visualizar os 2 tipos de licenças para empresas!

Comment: Muito caro, vou tentar o xamarin studio, pois quero apenas desenvolver para ios ja tenho iphone, para android irei continuar desenvolvendo nativo, então nesse caso é uma boa opção?

Comment: Qual o melhor xamarin studio ou forms?

Comment: Acredito que sim, no futuro você pode migrar o Android. Então a versão gratuita não suporta o Xamarin.Forms mas já que vai manter o android em java não precisa do Xamarin.Forms e se com o tempo ele se adequar as suas necessidades e desejar a migração do Android você faz a aquisição da licença e utiliza base code e ui code pra ambos os SO.

De uma olhada nesse CodeNameOne que o @user3509063 indicou parece promissor!

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada rápida sobre esse CodeNameOne e parece ser bom ele utiliza Java como base code já o Xamarin utiliza C#. Pra mim ainda prefiro o Xamarin pq o CodeNameOne utiliza IDE desenvolvida em java.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16597/discussion-between-war-lock-and-premiere).

Comment: Tranquilo, já estou lá!

Comment: Estou mandando mensagem no batepapo.

Comment: @Premiere por que é necessário o Mac para desenvolver com o Xamarin? Só para testar? Se for, o (Test Cloud)[http://xamarin.com/test-cloud] não resolveria?

Comment: Não, o Test Cloud testa em vários dispositivos mas é um processo automático. No caso você pode até desenvolver sem o Mac mas na hora de testar precisa ter um.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, você falou que desenvolve em Java para Android, recomendo dar uma olhada no Plugin CodenameOne, você desenvolve em Java, direto no NetBeans é gratuito e tem um imenso suporte técnico.

Comment: Com esse plugin se desenvolve em Java para iOS?

Comment: Sim! Ele é bem útil e o suporte em caso de dúvida ainda é imenso.

Comment: Desenvolve pra android, e pode compilar o mesmo projeto para ios? ou tem que desenvolver separado?